# VBA call property from with class

Tags: ms-access, vba

In VBA I would like to call a `Property Let()` from within my class constructor rather than just setting the variable in the constructor. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, you're looking for the `Me` keyword.

```
Option Explicit

Dim l_ As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Me.l = 5
End Sub

Public Property Let l(newl As Long)
    l_ = newl
End Property
```

Comment: You understood it perfectly, that's exactly what I was looking for. I knew it had to be something simple. Thank you very much!